# turn on site collection features programatically sharepoint csom

Tags: .net, sharepoint, csom

I'm trying to turn on site collection features programatically on our on-premise environment using CSOM.

I keep getting the error:
`Feature with Id '7201d6a4-a5d3-49a1-8c19-19c4bac6e668' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.`

I check site collection features through the GUI and it is there so I presume it's turned on (and it's OOTB).

Why is this happening?

Code:

```
try
          {
            if (featureNode.Attributes != null)
            {
                string guid = featureNode.Attributes["ID"].Value;
                string featureName = featureNode.Attributes["FeatureName"].Value;

                 Guid featureGUID = new Guid(guid);
                 if (isSiteColl)
                 {
                     currentFeatures.Add(featureGUID, false, FeatureDefinitionScope.Site);
                      currentContext.ExecuteQuery();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      currentFeatures.Add(featureGUID, false, FeatureDefinitionScope.None);
                       currentContext.ExecuteQuery();
                   }
               }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're trying to activate is *Metadata Navigation and Filtering`, right?

The problem is in this part of code:

```
if (isSiteColl)
{
    currentFeatures.Add(featureGUID, false, FeatureDefinitionScope.Site);
    currentContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
else
{
    currentFeatures.Add(featureGUID, false, FeatureDefinitionScope.None);
    currentContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I don't know what the value of `isSiteColl` is, as it is not assigned in the code you've provided. But for *Metadata Navigation and Filtering*, neither `FeatureDefinitionScope.Site` nor `FeatureDefinitionScope.None` is right.

This enumeration indicates where feature **definition** is, not where you want to install it. The right values are:

- `Farm` for OOB features and the ones installed as part of custom farm solutions.
- `Site` for sandboxed solutions and features generated when you export site as a template.

This is based on my experience. I've struggled with the same problem, as this is very poorly documented on MSDN. I have no idea when you should use `Web` and `None` values.